# Parallel Inserts/Updates in a SQL Server table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, multithreading, entity-framework

I have a multithread environment and every thread wants to select a row (or insert it if it does not exist) in a table and increment something in it.

Basically, every thread does something like this :

```
using (var context = new Entity.DBContext()) {
    if(!context.MyTable.Any(...)) {
        var obj = new MyTable() {
            SomeValue = 0
        };
        context.MyTable.Add(obj)
    }
    var row = context.MyTable.SingleOrDefault(...);
    row.SomeValue += 1;
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Problem in a example : a specific row has SomeValue = 0.
Two thread select this specific row at the same time, they both see 0.
-> they both increment it one time, and the final result in SomeValue will be 1, but we want it to be 2.

I assume that the thread that arrives just after the other should wait (using a lock ?) for the first one to be over. But i can't make it work properly.

Thanks.

Comment: To confirm - what database system are you using? This should probably be solved at the SQL level.

Comment: I agree with Damien_The_Unbeliever. You should use a [RowVersion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776(v=sql.120).aspx) to ensure atomar access.

Comment: I use EntityFramework and SQL-Server.

Comment: The problem you are seeing is the EF uses separate read/write statements and there is no serializable transaction.  If you are truly just incrementing a field by +1, then better to use a SP (or direct SQL statement) to do exactly that in a single update statement.  If you try to wrap a serializable TX around the entity read/write, usually deadlocks ensue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming SQL Server, you can do something like this:

```
create table T1 (
    Key1 int not null,
    Key2 int not null,
    Cnt int not null
)
go
create procedure P1
    @Key1 int,
    @Key2 int
as
    merge into T1 WITH (HOLDLOCK) t
    using (select @Key1 k1,@Key2 k2) s
    on
        t.Key1 = s.k1 and
        t.Key2 = s.k2
    when matched then update set Cnt = Cnt + 1
    when not matched then insert (Key1,Key2,Cnt) values (s.k1,s.k2,0)
    output inserted.Key1,inserted.Key2,inserted.Cnt;
go
exec P1 1,5
go
exec P1 1,5
go
exec P1 1,3
go
exec P1 1,5
go
```

(Note, it doesn't have to be a procedure, and I'm just calling it from one thread to show how it works)

Results:

```
Key1        Key2        Cnt
----------- ----------- -----------
1           5           0

Key1        Key2        Cnt
----------- ----------- -----------
1           5           1

Key1        Key2        Cnt
----------- ----------- -----------
1           3           0

Key1        Key2        Cnt
----------- ----------- -----------
1           5           2
```

Even with multiple threads calling this, I believe that it should serialize access. I'm producing outputs just to show that each caller can also know what value they've set the counter to (here, the column `Cnt`), even if another caller immediately afterwards changes the value.

Comment: Using `merge` in a multithreaded environment is a really bad idea, see [Aaron Bertrand at mssqltips](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/)  We were bitten by several of those issues at work.

Comment: It actually works pretty great, it seems like doing the Insert/Update in a stored procedure avoid the inserts/updates to be executed at the exact same time, every update is then considered. Thanks Damien_The_Unbeliever ;)

Comment: Final note : a lock had to be used in SQL requests (with (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK)

Answer (score 0):

If only one process writes to the database at the same time, you could wrap your code in a C# `lock(obj) {}` statement. That limits you to one active query which will not make optimal use of the database, but if that's okay it's a simple solution.

Another option is to create a unique index on the columns that define whether the row already exists.  If you `insert` over that, you'll get a `duplicate key` exception.  You can `catch` that in C# and run an `update` instead.

If you can write raw SQL, you can use locking hints, for example `with (updlock, holdlock)`, or `set isolation level serializable`.  That probably gives you the best performance at the cost of complexity.